# how to rewrite url with html extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can i rewrite my website urls as given below detail

`static-page.php?statictour=agra-jaipur` to `agra-jaipur.html`

our code is 
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ static-page.php?statictour=$1 [NC,L]`
above code working but index.html file not working when this code apply
anybody can help ?

Comment: Solved . worked great below code to exclude index.html
<code>RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*/)?index\.html$ [NC]</code>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that **index.html** also matches the pattern **^([A-Za-z0-9-]+).html$** and  redirects to **/static-page.php** .

You need to exclude index.html from the rule :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.html$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).html$ static-page.php?statictour=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: still not working also above code 
i think this is conflict with html extension bcoz i am using html extension in dynamic url